# The infimum over probability generating function

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, generating-functions

Let $Z$ be an integer-valued random variable, $\mathbf{P}(Z \in\mathbb{Z})= 1$, and let $G$ be its probability generating function, $G$ is finite. Prove that for every $k\in\mathbb{Z}$
$$
\mathbf{P} (Z\geq k)\leq \inf_{s\geq1}(s^{-k}G(s)).
$$

I have that $G(s)=\sum_{k\in \mathbb{Z}}s^kp_k=Es^Z<\infty$, where $p_k=\mathbf{P}(Z=k)$. Using Markov's inequality for $c>0$
$$
P(X\geq c)\leq \frac{Eg(X)}{g(c)}
$$
I can see that for constants $c>0$
$$
P(s^Z\geq s^c)\leq \frac{Es^Z}{s^c}=s^{-c}Es^Z=s^{-c}G(s)
$$
holds, because if $s\geq 1$, then $Z\geq c$ if and only if $s^Z\geq s^c$. But what happens when $c$ is negative? I have to show that the inequality holds for all integers $c$. When is it necessary to use the infimum?

Comment: The inequality will also be true for negative $c$. $Z\geq c \iff s^Z \geq s^{c}$ for all $c$ as long as $s > 1$.

Comment: Oh, I get that now, $s^Z$ is a non-negative random variable and $s^c>0$ for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$. I also get, that the inequality holds for all $s\geq1$, so it must be true for the $s$ which gives the smallest value of $s^{-c}G(s)$, but still, why can I take infimum from  the right side. I'm sorry infimums confuse me alot.

Comment: So the inequality will hold for all values of $s > 1$. You can choose the value of $s$ that gives you the tightest bound, i.e. the smallest value on RHS. The smallest value is obtained by taking an infimum. You can informally think of infimum as a minimum, if that helps.